# How can I check the load and existence of the module (Yii2)?

Tags: yii2

I generated module siteadmin using GII, it appeared in the frontend/module folder. Next, I added it in the main.php front-end configuration file

```
'siteadmin' => [
    'class' => 'app\modules\siteadmin\Module',
],
```

But the domain.net/siteadmin address shows a 404 error. Individual routs in the urlManager for this address are not created. How can I check all, and understand what is wrong and where is the error? Debug panel works, but it says: route to run: `site/error`

Comment: dump `Yii::$app->modules;` if it's not there, double check your config file, maybe you added it to components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to confirm the `namespace` of the `module` class if you generated that module for the frontend the module class file `frontend/modules/siteadmin/Siteadmin.php` should have the `namespace` like.

```
namespace frontend\modules\siteadmin;
```

and the directory structure should look like below

[image]

The `Siteadmin.php` file that you are seeing in the above picture is the main module file.

If the directory structure is like I stated above in the picture then you should add the module inside the `frontend/config/main.php` like below

```
'modules' => [
        'siteadmin' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\modules\siteadmin\Siteadmin',
        ],
    ],
```

Then you can access it like `http://example.com/siteadmin/default` or if there is any other controller than `default` you can provide that name.

Answer (score 1):

Try using explicit frontend  application name  eg:

```
'siteadmin' => [
   'class' => 'frontend\modules\siteadmin\Module',
],
```

Comment: `yii2` does not create the module file with name `Module` instead it is the actual Module name.

Comment: ....................... $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';........'modules' => [
        'gridview' => [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'